# Is there a standard to connect PIR sensors to own hardware?

Tags: standard, pir

Does anybody know if there is a standard to connect PIR sensors to own hardware. E.g., I've seen that V+, GND, VIN (with load resistor) are required, but is this all?

Comment: There are single ended, differential sensors, analog and digital output types, pick one.

Comment: You can take a look at BISS0001 datasheet, but the bad thing is that this sheet is so brief that is pretty hard to understand. However this is the most common and cheap IC to drive a PIR motion sensor.